# Get HTML as string

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I connect to a website and grab the HTML into a string?  I would like to do this behind the scenes of my application.  I want to parse this information in a later screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point check the [RIM documentation on HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) (scroll to "Example using HttpConnection").

The example reads the response as a byte array, but it can be easily changed to read a String if you are OK in Java SE.

Another point is to use a proper transport (BIS, BES, TCP, WiFi, etc. - it should be usable on the particular device). For transport detection you can check [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206243#M29104).

Comment: also, "new String(byte[])" is an option with the byte array -- leaves you more flexible, as byte[] can be a very functional data structure

Comment: @Arhimed - How would one change it to a string?

Comment: @Christopher: The simplest ways are either via `new String(byte[] data)` or `new String(byte[] data, String encoding)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getContentsFrom(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String content = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content += inputLine;
    }
    in.close();
    return content;
}
```

Comment: java.net.URL is not supported.